# Does ActionDispatch instance can't be stored in a class variable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a controller which has two methods: upload and submit

I can ensure that the upload method is executed before submit is called.

in the upload, I have such code:

```
def upload
    @file = params[:avatar]
    ...
end
```

in the submit, I have such code:

```
def submit
    ...
    user.avatar = @file
    ...
end
```

but it seems that the @file is nil.

Where am I wrong?....

I'm using Rails 3.2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instance variables in controllers do not persist between requests. Every request creates a new instance of the controller class so the `@file` you save in `upload` goes away when `upload` finishes. Then, when a new request comes in that is routed to your `submit` method, Rails will create a new instance of your controller class and call `submit` on it. Since you have two instances of the class, you have two sets of instance variables and they won't share your `@file`.

You have to arrange for the `@file` to be stored in your database, session, form, etc. between requests and then your `submit` has to load it from where ever it is stored and assign it to `user.avatar`.